# Query a google spreadsheet cell from antoher cell

Tags: google-sheets

I have two spreadsheets  Documents DocA  and DocB

```
    A               B           C
1    uid                serial_no   ph
2   356307042189331 3123958     912345678900
3   356307046077540 3966305     923451245123
4   356307046092465 3966407     978458784578
5   356307046098678 3970932     971548745125
```

In DocB

```
    A               B
1   serial_no      uid
2   3123958
3   3284728
4   3284655
```

I am trying to get A2 from DocA into B2 in DocB with the following code

=QUERY(ImportRange("[key]","Sheet1!A:C"),"Select Col1, Col2 where Col1='"&A2&"'",1)

I get

```
uid serial_no
```

in Cell B2 instead of the value in Cell A2 of DocA

Comment: It will be helpful, if you can share a sample spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do what you want.

```
=(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("[key]","Sheet1!A2:B"),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col2 contains" & "'" & A2 & "'"))
```

Notice That the Sheet1!A2:B starts with A2 instead of A and the 1 at the end (header Row) is not there. The way you had it will bring in the header (uid) on one row and the value on the row below. I also changed = to contains. Also note the change in quotes around A2.

Comment: Thanks @Ed Nelson that eased my troubles

Comment: You are welcome @Kaippally If this solved your problem, please approve the answer. Thanks.